# Rails can't succed to use before_filter for admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, before-filter

I try to use before_filter for admin page, I have my login page and my dashboard  etc.

so this is my `admin_user.rb` :

```
 ActiveAdmin.register AdminUser do     
index do                            
column :email                     
column :current_sign_in_at        
column :last_sign_in_at           
column :sign_in_count             
default_actions                   
end                                 

 filter :email                       

form do |f|                         
  f.inputs "Admin Details" do       
  f.input :email                  
  f.input :password               
  f.input :password_confirmation  
  end                               
f.actions                         
end
```

and, in the controller for the page I want to protect, I've put on the top this :

```
before_filter check_if_admin


 def check_if_admin
    if signed_in?
  #    raise 'Only admins allowed!' unless current_user.admin?
    raise 'Only admins allowed!'
 else
raise 'Please sign in!'
 end
end
```

And so I got an error :

```
undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class
```

from de `_form.html.erb` of my controller ...

How can I do that ? I acces certain page when admin.

Thanks!

note :  I'm a beginner in web development, sorry If this seems to be easy to you :)

EDIT

model `admin_user.rb` :

```
class AdminUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
   # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
   devise :database_authenticatable, 
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

   # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me
    # attr_accessible :title, :body
   end
```

Comment: Do you have model admin_user.rb ?

Comment: I edit my post to post it

Answer (score 0):

Check out the documentation for form_for:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html

Comment: the problem is not comming from the _form, but the controller. If I comment 'before_filter check_if_admin' line, it just worked as before.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method

```
def check_if_admin
    if current_admin_user_signed_in?
     raise 'Welcome Admin'
    else
    raise 'Only admins allowed!'
 end
end
```

Comment: same result if I call  'before_filter check_if_admin'  outside methods, if I call it in a method, i get a runtimeError (admin or not)

Comment: did you run rake db:migrate and added record for admin?

Comment: added record for admin ? I can login if this is the question